# How to set a dynamic object to the correct type

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, casting

This is my function to move the scrollbars (I have horizontal one and a vertical one)

```
    private void moveTheScroll(object sbar, int scrollDiff)
    {
        if (sbar is HScrollBar)
        {
            int newScrollvalue = ((HScrollBar)sbar).Value + scrollDiff;
            if (((HScrollBar)sbar).Minimum < newScrollvalue &&
                newScrollvalue < ((HScrollBar)sbar).Maximum)
                ((HScrollBar)sbar).Value = newScrollvalue;
        }
        else if (sbar is VScrollBar)
        {
            int newScrollvalue = ((VScrollBar)sbar).Value + scrollDiff;
            if (((VScrollBar)sbar).Minimum < newScrollvalue &&
                newScrollvalue < ((VScrollBar)sbar).Maximum)
            ((VScrollBar)sbar).Value = scrollDiff;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to to not typecast the object every single time I want to use it and make an alias instead?
Something similar to this (this doesnt work because v cannot be initialized)

```
var v;
if(sbar is HScrollBar)
    v = (HScrollBar)sbar;
else if(sbar is VScrollBar)
    v = (VScrollBar)sbar;
v.Value = newValue;
```

Comment: Is there an interface or base class both HScrollBar and VScrollBar implements ?

Comment: Yes, I've used this [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement the scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

If both types are inheriting from [`Scrollbar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar(v=vs.110).aspx) class then you just need to perform one cast:

```
private void moveTheScroll(object sbar, int scrollDiff)
{
    var scrollBar = sbar as ScrollBar;

    if(scrollBar != null)
    {
         int newScrollvalue = scrollBar.Value + scrollDiff;
         // do other works with scrollBar...
    }
}
```

Comment: Better yet, you can avoid casting altogether if you change the parameter's type.